# jquery-resizable-columns refresh after ng-hide

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have got a HTML table with https://github.com/dobtco/jquery-resizable-columns resize plugin.

I have to add column hiding functionality so I've added `ng-hide` directives to the columns with double click event on every columns header to switch hide flag to true and an 'Unhide all' button to switch all flags to false.

Problem: after hiding a column resize handlers stay intact. When I click any of them, they are being refreshed and moved to the proper places.

How can I force handlers refreshing after hiding a column?

Example: http://plnkr.co/edit/balnDZPWqVP5y0Mx7mhT?p=preview

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is, the plnkr seems to work pretty well, no? Can you elaborate on the exact issue?

Comment: When you start this example, you've got a table with 5 columns.
When you hover the mouse cursor over a column separator you can see a cursor changes to resize.
Now double click a column - it should hide.
Try to hover a mouse over any between column line and see if it changes. When you move the cursor slightly to the side, you can see that it changes somewhere. This is where resize handler is after hiding a column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
$('#tab').resizableColumns('syncHandleWidths')
```

This will refresh the column sizes. The trick is to call this method *after* the DOM has been reloaded. Otherwise, the column has not yet disappeared from the DOM, and the column sizes will not be correct. This is where angular's `$timeout` service comes in handy (don't forget to inject it):

```
$timeout(function(){$('#tab').resizableColumns('syncHandleWidths');});
```

Forked plunkr [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/xfdUYdOCv3O0iT9MFyOm?p=preview).